# FOR loops giving no result or error in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I am running the following code:

```
 disc<-for (i in 1:33) {
 m=n[i]
 xbar<-sum(data[i,],na.rm=TRUE)/m 
 Sx <- sqrt(sum((data[i,]-xbar)^2,na.rm=TRUE)/(m-1))
 Sx
 i=i+1}
```

Running it:

```
 >disc
 NULL
```

Why is it giving me NULL?

Comment: What is `n`? What is `data`?

Comment: When I don't use the loop, I have to run them one-by-one. Running them one-by-one, I get Sx=4.5,3.5,....

Comment: Wait....why are you trying to assign a `for` loop to a variable? I'm not certain that that's a valid assignment, and even if it is, it's quite a bizarre thing to do.

Comment: length of 'n' is 44.
dim(data) = 33 x 25

Comment: If I change my 5th line to 

     print(Sx)

I get the desired answer but nothing gets stored in dics

Comment: Yes, but **why are you trying to assign a `for` loop to a variable**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is from the documentation for `for`, accessible via  `` ?`for` ``:

> ‘for’, ‘while’ and ‘repeat’ return ‘NULL’ invisibly.

Perhaps you are looking for something along the following lines:

```
library(plyr)
disc <- llply(1:33, function(i) {
  m=n[i]
  xbar<-sum(data[i,],na.rm=TRUE)/m 
  Sx <- sqrt(sum((data[i,]-xbar)^2,na.rm=TRUE)/(m-1))
  Sx
})
```

Other variants exists -- the `ll` in `llply` stands for "list in, list out". Perhaps your intended final result is a data frame or an array -- appropriate functions exist.

The code above is a plain transformation of your example. We might be able to do better by splitting `data` right away and forgetting the otherwise useless count variable `i` (untested, as you have provided no data):

```
disc <- daply(cbind(data, n=n), .(), function(data.i) {
  m=data.i$n
  xbar<-sum(data.i,na.rm=TRUE)/m 
  sqrt(sum((data.i-xbar)^2,na.rm=TRUE)/(m-1))
})
```

See also [the `plyr` website](http://plyr.had.co.nz/) for more information.

Related (if not a duplicate): [R - How to turn a loop to a function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3407610/946850)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Should have realized you weren't going to leave it there.

Comment: @ayeshamalik: That's just because `for` doesn't return anything, as the docs read and I have indicated at the very top of my answer.

Comment: @krlmlr - The 2nd code you wrote didn't give the right answers.

Comment: @ayeshamalik: Could you please `dput` your data? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/946850

Comment: @krlmlr why are you using extra package here? I see also that you give a base solution (with a spelling mistake) in an another comment.

Comment: @agstudy: `laply` is from `plyr`, `lapply` is from `base`. I prefer `plyr`, it's clean, simple, powerful. By all means, please do provide a "base" answer, too.

Comment: @krlmlr the problem here is not using lapply or plyr! That'said( even I know that plyr is a good package), but clearly here no need to use it. It is slower than a simple lapply.

Answer (score 2):

krlmlr's answer shows you how to fix your code, but to explain your original problem in more abstract terms: A for loop allows you to run the same piece of code multiple times, but it doesn't store the results of running that code for you- you have to do that yourself.

Your current code only really assigns a single value, `Sx`, for each run of the for loop. On the next run, a new value is put into the `Sx` variable, so you lose all the previous values. At the end, you'll just end up with whatever the value of `Sx` was on the last run through the loop.

To save the results of a for loop, you generally need to add them to a vector as you go through, e.g.

```
# Create the empty results vector outside the loop
results = numeric(0)
for (i in 1:10) {
  current_result = 3 + i
  results = c(results, current_result)
}
```

Comment: I got it. This really helped. Removing Sx does the job in my case.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ayeshamalik: Just for the sake of completeness, the `plyr` equivalent of the code above: `results <- laply(10, function(i) 3+i)`

Comment: @ayeshamalik: No, wrong: `results <- laply(1:10, function(i) 3+i)` is the correct version.

Comment: @Marius you should know that it is better to preallocate before looping!

Answer (score 1):

In R `for` can't return a value. The unique manner to return a value is within a function. So the solution here, is to wrap your loop within a function. For example:

```
getSx <- function(){
  Sx <- 0
  disc <- for (i in 1:33) {
    m=n[i]
    xbar <- sum(data[i,],na.rm=TRUE)/m 
    Sx <- sqrt(sum((data[i,]-xbar)^2,na.rm=TRUE)/(m-1))
  }
  Sx
}
```

Then you call it:

```
 getSx()
```

Of course you can avoid the side effect of using a `for` by `lapply` or by giving a vectorized But this is another problem: You should maybe give a reproducible example and explain a little bit what do you try to compute.